# C# Windows Forms- How to change a single property of more than one control with the same parent?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way I can make it so a certain property of several controls can be changed using say, hypothetically, a FOR loop? All these controls I am mentioning have the same parent which is another panel. I've tried searching for answers but I can't find them or some of them talk about other things.

```
private void Method(string name, string t1, string t2)
        {
            name.Text = name;
            paragraph1.Text = t1;
            paragraph2.Text = t2;

            paragraph3.Visible = false; 
            paragraph3.Visible = false; 
            paragraph3.Visible = false; 
            image1.Visible = false;

            panel1.Visible = false; 
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }
```

Thank you!

Edit: made this more generalized for people who wish to see this and understand how to list controls

Comment: Did you check the panel's `.Controls` collection?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly what you have now is what I'd expect of a WinForms project -- it's instantly readable.

However, if you'd like, you can do the following instead:

```
Control[] controlarray = new Control[]
{
    lblLargeText3,
    lblLargeText4,
    lblLargeText5,
    pnlLargeExample,
    btnYes,
    btnNo
}
private void InitiateLargeDialogue(string title, string text1, string text2, Size size)
{
    lblLargeTitle.Text = title;
    lblLargeText1.Text = text1;
    lblLargeText2.Text = text2;

    foreach(Control c in controlarray)
        c.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Hey man, if you don't mind, I know this is a bit outdated, but can you edit your comment so that it is more generalized and fits my post so it can help others because it may be confusing for people who don't understand my code, something like this:

Control[] controlarray = new Control[]
{
    paragraph3,
    paragraph4,
    paragraph5,
    image1,
    panel1,
    panel2
}
private void Method(string name, string t1, string t2)
{
    name.Text = name;
    paragraph1.Text = t1;
    paragraph2.Text = t2;

    foreach(Control c in controlarray)
        c.Visible = false;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Label> listLabel = new List<Label>();
public void test()
{
    listLabel.Add(new Label() { Text = "aaa" });
    listLabel.Add(new Label() { Text = "bbb" });
    listLabel.Add(new Label() { Text = "ccc" });

    int count = 1;
    foreach(Label l in listLabel)
    {
        l.Text += $" {count++}";
        Console.WriteLine(l.Text);
    }
}
```

// result
aaa 1
bbb 2
ccc 3

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation on what does your code do?